# Echo same MySql query in different part of the page

Tags: php, mysql, cordova, phonegap-build

This might be a silly question but I am trying to call the same query to two different pages but once I call the second time, the link to the page would not work anymore. The way I have it setup at the moment is that all the pages in the app are on one file (index.php). I am linking to each page by using id (href="#page2"). If I call the same query, depending on the order of pages, only the "top" page, or in this case, Page 1 will work. I tried changing the variable names so that it would treat it as a different call but to no avail.

I am developing this app using Phonegap Build and it would be really helpful if ANYBODY can help.

**Page 1**

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">    
<form action="post-comment.php" method="POST">
        <h3>COMMENT</h3>
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name"><br />
        <textarea name="comment" cols="50" rows="2" placeholder="Enter Comment"></textarea><br />
        <input type="submit" value="comment" onClick="javascript.ajax_post()"></input><br />
        </form>

    <?php
    $find_comments = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM COMMENTS");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($find_comments))
    {
    $comment_name = $row['name'];
    $comment = $row['comment'];

    echo "$comment_name - $comment<br />" ;
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

**Page 2**

```
<div data-role="page" id="page2">
    <?php
        $find_comments1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM COMMENTS");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($find_comments1))
        {
        $comment_name1 = $row['name'];
        $comment1 = $row['comment'];

        echo "$comment_name1 - $comment1<br />" ;
        }
        ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Where's your connection string? mind posting the index.php file ?

Comment: Look at the answer below this may not solve your issue but try using this method for querying your database.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `PDO` - [DOC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)  instead of `mysql`, I would do it this way :

Connect to your database :

```
 $hostdb = "your_host";
 $namedb = "db_name";
 $userdb = "user_name";
 $passdb = "pass";

 $options =  array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
    try {
           $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostdb; dbname=$namedb; charset=utf8", $userdb, $passdb, $options);
                    return $db;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
                    $err = "DB Connection Error, because: ". $e->getMessage();
                    print $err;
        }
```

Now you can use `$db` to connect to your database in your script and fetch comments :

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">    
<form action="post-comment.php" method="POST">
        <h3>COMMENT</h3>
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name"><br />
        <textarea name="comment" cols="50" rows="2" placeholder="Enter Comment"></textarea><br />
        <input type="submit" value="comment" onClick="javascript.ajax_post()"></input><br />
</form>

    <?php
    $find_comments ="SELECT * FROM COMMENTS";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($find_comments);
    if(!$stmt->execute()){
        print "error";
    } else {
         $comments = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
         foreach($comments as $comment) {
              echo $comment['name']."</br>";
              echo $comment['comment'] ;

       }
         $stmt->closeCursor(); // Close connection

    }

    ?>
</div>
```

then in your Page2 just do the same as Page1. You can define the SQL statement as a global variable and re-use it in your second query. just make sure to use `closeCursor();` to close your db connection.

Comment: thanks AwRak for a rapid comment. Can you assure me that the method you suggested will allow me to call the same query from different pages without "disabling" the later pages? 

I don't really know much about PDO so from what I can see it is just a more efficient way to connect to db and call queries, but can it fix the problem?

Comment: I cannot assure you anything Paulo as I haven't seen the whole code and I do not quite understand how your scripts are called. But I can assure you to stick to PDO when handling Database queries and Yes in this example $find_comments is just a string containing your SQL statement, so if "page2" this variable is accessible then yes you can. Let me know how it goes